# Solve logarithmic equation $\log_{\frac{x}{5}}(x^2-8x+16)\geq 0$

Tags: logarithms

Find $x$ from logarithmic equation:
$$\log_{\frac{x}{5}}(x^2-8x+16)\geq 0 $$ 
This is how I tried:
$$x^2-8x+16>0$$
$$ (x-4)^2>0 \implies x \not = 4$$
then
$$\log_{\frac{x}{5}}(x^2-8x+16)\geq \log_{\frac{x}{5}}(\frac{x}{5})^0 $$ 
because of base $\frac{x}{5}$, we assume $x \not\in (-5,5)$, then
$$x^2-8x+16 \geq 1$$
$$ (x-3)(x-5) \geq 0 \implies$$
$$ \implies x \in {(- \infty,-5) \cup (5, \infty)} \cap x\not = 4 $$
But this is wrong, because the right solution is $$x \in {(3,4) \cup (4,6)} $$

I'm sorry if I used the wrong terms, English is not my native language.

Comment: $x$ cannot be $5$ because $\log_1x=\text{undefined}$

Comment: First, the base of logarithm can't be negative, 0 or 1, but it's possible that the base is between 0 and 1. Second, I think the answer should be  $$x \in {[3,4) \cup (4,5) \cup (5,+\infty)} $$...

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I mentioned "we assume $x\not\in (-5, 5)$"

Comment: But your "right solution" includes $5$.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I guess the book has made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $$\displaystyle \log_{\frac{x}{5}}(x^2-8x+16)\geq 0\;,$$ Here function is defined when $\displaystyle \frac{x}{5}>0$ and $\displaystyle \frac{x}{5}\neq 1$

and $(x-4)^2>0$. So we get $x>0$ and $x\neq 5$ and $x\neq 4$

If $$\displaystyle \; \bullet\;  \frac{x}{5}>1\Rightarrow x>5\;,$$ Then $$\displaystyle \log_{\frac{x}{5}}(x^2-8x+16)\geq 0\Rightarrow (x^2-8x+16)\geq 1$$

So we get $$\displaystyle x^2-8x+15\geq 0\Rightarrow (x-3)(x-5)\geq 0$$

So we get $x>5$

If $$\displaystyle \; \bullet 0<\frac{x}{5}<1\Rightarrow 0<x<5\;,$$ Then $$\displaystyle \log_{\frac{x}{5}}(x^2-8x+16)\geq 0\Rightarrow (x^2-8x+16)\leq 1$$

So we get $$\displaystyle (x-3)(x-5)\leq 0$$

So $$3\leq x<5-\left\{4\right\}$$

So our  final Solution is $$\displaystyle x\in \left[3,4\right)\cup \left(4,5\right)\cup \left(5,\infty\right)$$

Comment: $(x-4)^2\geq0$ not $>0$, so $4$ will also be included.

Comment: @adityaagarwal please understand properly the behavior of logarithmic functions

Answer (score 1):

Logarithmic equation:

$$\log_{\frac{x}{5}}(x^2-8x+16)\geq 0 $$

In general:

## $$\log_{f(x)}(g(x))\geq 0 $$

The general solution to this has **two cases**.

## **Case 1:**$$ f(x) \in {(0,1)} \cap g(x) \in {(0,1]}  $$

## **Case 2:**$$ f(x) \in {(1,\infty)} \cap g(x) \in {[1,\infty)}  $$

## **Solution Set:**

## $$ \implies x \in {(CASE 1) \cup (CASE2)}  $$

This will give the desired result for the demand of the logarithm to be non-negative. Comment if you want to know how the cases arise.

Final Solution: $$\displaystyle x\in \left[3,4\right)\cup \left(4,5\right)\cup \left(5,\infty\right)$$

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+the+inequality:+%5B%2F%2Fmath:log((x%2F5),+(x%5E2-8x%2B16))%3E%3D0%2F%2F%5D](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20the%20inequality:%20%5B%2F%2Fmath:log((x%2F5),%20(x%5E2-8x%2B16))%3E%3D0%2F%2F%5D)

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_{\frac{x}{5}}(x^2-8x+16)\geq 0$$
$$=\frac{\log{(x^2-8x+16)}}{\log\frac{x}{5}}\geq0$$
So $x$ is non-positive. And now raising both sides on the base $10$.
$$x^2-8x+16\geq1$$
$$x^2-8x+15\geq0$$
$$(x-5)(x-3)\geq0$$
$$x\geq5; \ x\geq3$$
But $x$ cannot be $5$. So answer is $[3,5)\cup(5,\infty)$

Comment: This is wrong please take it down.