# How to solve this logarithm inequality with absolute value as its base?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, absolute-value

How to deal with this ?

$$\log_{|1 - x|} (x+5)>2 $$

the $|1-x|$ is the base of the logarithm.

I tried this below approach but it seems not the complete solution.
\begin{align}
\frac{\log(x+5)}{\log|1-x|} & > 2\\
{\log(x+5)} & > 2{\log|1-x|}\\
{\log(x+5)} & > {\log|1-x|^2}\\
(x+5) & >|1-x|^2\\
(x+5) & >(1-x)^2\\
(x+5) & >1-2x+x^2\\
x^2-3x-4& < 0
\end{align}
$$ -1<x<4 $$
I also checked with wolframalpha.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+%5Babsolut(1-x),+(x%2B5)%5D%3C2

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You can't just multiply the inequality by $\log|1-x|$ you must first divide it into cases when it's positive and when it's negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Look at the pictures. You will see there are two cases to the problem.

Here is a link to : [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20the%20inequality:%20%5B%2F%2Fmath:log(%7C1-x%7C,%20x%2B5)%3E2%2F%2F%5D)

Hope this helps. If you need help in solving the individual inequalities, comment and I will show this as well.

Comment: Please [type out your equations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116050/259305).

Comment: sorry. I'm new so still getting familiar with Latex

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).
Btw, it's not "[graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)".

Comment: yeah sorry. graph theory is another thing i realized someone told me.

Comment: Very nice solution +1

Comment: @navinstudent thank you. I saw you saw my similar but more complicated question. Thanks in advance for providing a general solution to my question. And thanks for editing my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I didnot edit your question.It was @Did who edited the question.I also find your question very complicated.

Comment: @Sid, My little brother and I thank you for helping us.
Now, I can see the problem much more clearly.

Comment: @Sid, My little brother and I thank you for helping us.
Now, I can see the problem much more clearly.

one question..
about
$$ 0<(x+5)/(1-x)^2 <1 $$

on this part $ 0<(x+5)/(1-x)^2 $, isn't the solution should be $ x>-5, x<1, x>1 $?

I also checked with wolframalpha.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+the+inequality:+%5B%2F%2Fmath:0+%3C(x%2B5)%2F(1-x)%5E2%2F%2F%5D

could you guide me one more time?

Comment: @codelearner777 you are correct. This is a standard method to solve logarithmic inequalities with a variable base. You need to check two regions.

Comment: i recommend you to solve this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422858/solve-logarithmic-equation-log-fracx5x2-8x16-geq-0 when you are finished sucessfully comment here. and I will give on more problem to clear ALL concepts

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Note that the base should be $$\left| 1-x \right| \neq 1\Rightarrow x\neq 0\quad \& \quad x\neq 2$$ and $$x+5>0\quad \Rightarrow \quad x>-5$$

Comment: finding the domain of the expression is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Developping kingW3's idea, we'll know why that's empty region in [the solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+%5Babsolut(1-x),+(x%2B5)%5D%3E2).  We first note that $x \ne 1$.

[image: wolfram alpha graph]

The problem in the question body is the transition from
$$\frac{\log(x+5)}{\log|1-x|} > 2\tag1\label1$$
to
$${\log(x+5)} > 2{\log|1-x|}.\tag2\label2$$

By neglecting case 2 below, we failed to capture the empty region $0 < x < 2$ in the range for $x$.

Case 1: $\log|1-x|>0 \iff |1-x|>1 \iff x<0$ or $x>2$.  Using OP's calculations above, we get $-1 < x < 0$ or $2 < x < 4$, which agrees with the graph of the linked Wolfram Alpha page.

Case 2: $\log|1-x|<0 \iff 0<|1-x|<1 \iff 0 < x < 1$ or $1 < x < 2$.

We should *reverse* the inequality \eqref{2} in this case since we're multiplying \eqref{1} by a *negative* denominator $\log|1-x|$.

$${\log(x+5)} < 2{\log|1-x|}$$

As a result, the inequalities in the question body that follow from \eqref{2} should be *reversed*, until $x^2-3x-4>0$, from which we deduce $x<-1$ or $x>4$.  The intersection of $(-\infty,-1)\cup(4,\infty)$ with $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ is *empty*, so *no* real value of $x$ satisfies case 2.

Hence the solution is $-1<x<0$ or $2<x<4$.

Comment: this is the right method but it is not working with my problem. See here: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201633/how-to-solve-this-logarithmic-inequality-with-another-logarithm-as-its-base][1]

Comment: @Sid Thx for referring me to your new problem.  I hope someone else can solve it for you.

Comment: I dont want a complete solution. I can solve all the inequalities myself. I just need a general solution.

Comment: @Sid Though I don't see one, I hope someone else can give it to you.

Comment: I'll wait. Maybe you can try I again. I edited my question and gave it more context. I explained a similar inequality and wrote the general solution. I just need one for the more complicated one now. I hope so too, I'll wait for someone to give it.